# Spring ResourceServer using RemoteTokenServices with uri to check access_token

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a configuration that enables web security and resource server as below

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableResourceServer
public class SpringSecurityConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

}
```

I also added the following properties

```
security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri: http://localhost:9090/oauth2/tokeninfo
security.oauth2.resource.token-info-uri: http://localhost:9090/oauth2/tokeninfo
```

But somehow the authentication manager in the created `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter` uses the `DefaultTokenServices` to `loadAuthentication`. How can I let it use the `RemoteTokenServices` by calling the uri I provided in the configuration to check the `access_token` sent by the client.